# Understanding the usage of "Philosophy" in Uncle Vanya

Tags: russian-language, wording-choice, anton-chekhov, uncle-vanya

In ["Uncle Vanya"](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1756/1756-h/1756-h.htm) by Chekhov, I noticed a usage of the word "philosophy" that seemed out of place.

> ASTROFF. A woman can only become a man's friend after having first
>   been his acquaintance and then his beloved—then she becomes his
>   friend.
>
> VOITSKI. What vulgar **philosophy**!

And

> HELENA. It is tedious, yes, and dreary! You all abuse my husband and
>   look on me with compassion; you think, "Poor woman, she is married to
>   an old man." How well I understand your compassion! As Astroff said
>   just now, see how you thoughtlessly destroy the forests, so that there
>   will soon be none left. So you also destroy mankind, and soon fidelity
>   and purity and self-sacrifice will have vanished with the woods. Why
>   cannot you look calmly at a woman unless she is yours? Because, the
>   doctor was right, you are all possessed by a devil of destruction; you
>   have no mercy on the woods or the birds or on women or on one another.
>
> VOITSKI. I don't like your **philosophy**.

While the word makes sense, it seemed like an awkward usage.

Was there any particular purpose to the using that particular word, like a historical, culture, etc. context? Or is it just an artifact of translation?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me; is there any particular reason you deleted it?

Comment: @Mithrandir someone commented that I didn't mention why I thought is was an awkward usage, then I realized I couldn't give any reason beside just being a native speaker and it sounding off. Didn't think that was a strong argument, so I deleted the question.